# How to keep order of records in database

Tags: algorithm, mongodb

I'm developing an app where records appear in certain order. Users are allowed to reorder records as they wish, and I need to store that. 
I have an order number for each record, but when they reorder records, that affects all records that go after that record - which could be quite expensive database operation.

Is there a clever way of storing record's order number, so that it doesn't affect many of the other records?

Comment: I depends on your use case which is not fully explained here, but embedded arrays may suit your purpose. So this question needs some further example information in order to get a good answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn can you please elaborate on embedded arrays solution?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in your question as yet to actually say which solution is the best one to use. So rather can you please elaborate on your question, otherwise you are leaving this open to just opinions, that are not really answers.

Comment: Users are allowed to add records that on the UI are only visible to them, at first records appear in chronological order - if user reorders records (say moves last record to top, with UI drag and drop) - that needs to be saved in to the database, so that next time user logs in - she can see her records in the order that she defined.

Comment: Comments here are not enough. Show a working example of what you are trying to achieve within your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a web application with at a high level similar requirements. I added two fields to a document which contained metadata about the user sortable list:

```
SortOrderVersion: integer
SortOrder: array of _id for documents
```

The `SortOrder` simply contained an ordered array of each document's _id.  It was that list was manipulated by the client. The second field, `SortOrderVersion` was used to optimistically protect changes by multiple clients simultaneously. If the version being sent matched what was stored via `findAndModify`, then the update was allowed, and the number was incremented to prevent further changes by other clients. (And as a bonus, the changes were pushed to the other clients via a web socket connection).

When doing it this way, the server would do the sorting based on the list before returning it to the client as it was cached, and didn't change frequently. I could have pushed the busy work of sorting to the client, I just didn't think it was necessary.

I had considered storing the documents as a subdocument in a sorted array within a single document, but in my case their were too many opportunities where multiple users would be editing the details of the subdocuments which complicated updates and reordering significantly.

While I didn't need it for this web application, by storing the sort order independently, I could have extended the application to provide sorting easily on a per user basis.